# How to zoom in and out text in web browser in ubuntu 20.04 instead of whole layout?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, zooming, webbrowser-app

i tried web browsers(firefox, google chrome) in windows, when i pinch with two finger on touchpad to zoom in and out it zooms the text or content not the layout of webpage.
but, in ubuntu 20.04 i know that pinch to zoom in and out mouse gestures does not work and shortcut like CTRL+- and CTRL+= zoom the layout of web browser.
is there any way to zoom-in/out content on ubuntu without zoom-in/out complete browser layout?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, head to "Settings". Find the "Zoom" section in the "General" tab. There you can select the default zoom level, and check "Zoom text only".

Chromium and Google Chrome do not have this feature. An extension [Zoom Text Only](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-text-only/jamhfhbppcmkgghlkeieococonlbppjg) can be used.